# Is there a way to pass variable as counter to list index in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry if i am asking very basic question but i am new to python and need help with below question

I am trying to write a file parser where i am counting number of occurrences(modified programs) mentioned in the file. 
I am trying to then store all the occurrences in a empty list and putting counter for each occurrence.

Till here all is fine
Now i am trying to create files based on the names captured in the empty list and store the lines that are not matching between in separate file but i am getting error index out of range as when i am passing el[count] is taking count as string and not taking count's value.
Can some one help

```
import sys
import re
count =1
j=0
k=0
el=[]
f = open("change_programs.txt", 'w+')
data = open("oct-released_diff.txt",encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')

for i in data:
    if len(i.strip()) > 0 and i.strip().startswith("diff --git"):
        count = count + 1
        el.append(i)
        fl=[]
    else:

        **filename = "%s.txt" % el[int (count)]**
        h = open(filename, 'w+')
        fl.append(i)
        print(fl, file=h)

el = '\n'.join(el)

print(el, file=f)
print(filename)
data.close()
```

Comment: `el[int (count)]` Check the value of `count` there. If you just want the last item in the list: `el[-1]`.

Comment: Also, you never close the `h` file. Look into using [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: That [-1] worked but now it is not able to create teh file and giving me error

Comment: h = open(filename, 'w+')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: Can you provide an example of an input (content of `change_programs.txt`) and the desired output?

Comment: can you add an example input / output to your question